# Groovy filtering array with findAll method

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

I am learning Groovy and I am trying to write an alternative to the following bit of Java code.

```
Collection<Record> records = requestHelper.getUnmatchedRecords();
Collection<Integer> recordIdentifiers = new ArrayList<>();
for (Record record : records){
    int rowId = record.getValue("RowID");
    if (rowId >= min && rowId <= max) {
        recordIdentifiers.add(rowId);
    }
}
```

When that bit of code is run recordIdentifiers should contain 50 items. This is my Groovy equivalent so far.

```
def records = requestHelper.getUnmatchedRecords()
def recordIdentifiers = records.findAll{record ->
    int rowId = record.getValue("RowId")
    rowId >= min && rowId <= max
}
```

For some reason the array contains 100 items after Groovy code is executed. All the examples of findAll() I have come across do simple comparisons when the array is constructed natively in Groovy, but how do you filter a Collection that you receive from a Java class?

Comment: what is 100 and 50 here?  how many are there in the `records`?  is the filter simply not working or are there duplicates in the `recordIdentifiers`?  At first glance the code looks ok.

Comment: As I discovered later on, my code was fine, but one of our junior developers produced a wrong data set for me to work with - it had duplicates, hence instead of 50 records I had 100. He's been shamed now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems strange. The following code works fine:

```
def records = [[r:3],[r:5],[r:6],[r:11],[r:10]]
def range = (1..10)
recordIdentifiers = records.findAll { range.contains(it.r) }
assert recordIdentifiers.size() == 4
```

Could You please provide a working example?